# It doesn't work properly on iframes with Firefox, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, iframe

This is my first question.

I have a page for image upload on my website. I made an `<iframe>` to avoid the whole page to refresh, and I'm using jQuery. When I tested it in Firefox, Firebug returns me two errors:

```
c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h, null) is null
$ is not defined => $('#omega').hide();
```

And it is not working. But when I tested it in other browsers, like IE5, IE6, IE7, IE9 and Opera, it works perfectly.

Why it is not working on Firefox?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In future, please don't write tags in your title like "jQuery - summary". Just write "summary". SO already has a tagging feature that is consistent, semantic and indexable.

Comment: Can you provide a testcase? We don't know what your code is...

Comment: My code is simple. There is a jQuery call in the main page, with a button. When you click the button, it call the .show() method of jQuery to show the iFrame. Inside iFrame, is another call to jQuery to detect the onChange on the uploader element.

Comment: Thanks for your introduction to SO, I'll do that in future. :D

Comment: @Ryan: Cheers. Don't forget to provide a testcase; not prose, but a _workable_ example. Perhaps on jsfiddle.net. We can't determine what you've done wrong if we can't see your code.

Comment: I've added a piece of my code to the main question.

Comment: @Ryan: Please provide a workable testcase on jsfiddle.net. A minute extract that doesn't even contain an `iframe` is not useful here.

Comment: Ok, give me 5 minutes...

Comment: @Ryan: Be sure to edit it into your question.

Comment: It was an jQuery's update problem. Updating my jQuery to lastest version, the problem is solved. Thanks for all :D

Comment: @Ryan: Glad you got it sorted. You should post that as an answer and self-accept it, or delete the question. [And see how the process of creating a testcase revealed the issue? :)]

Comment: I can't self-answer, because I don't have reputation. I'll wait 7 hours for self-answer. By this way, if someone have the same problem, it can be solved :D

Comment: Can you post the answer? I'll put it as accepted :D

Comment: @Ryan: Post it in 7 hours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution was to update jQuery to latest version.

This is a bug that was fixed in version 1.6.1 (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/, item #8763)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked correctly that there is no jQuery conflicting..? type of error what you receiving are most probably by conflicting of Jquery.

you just need to check it out..

Thanks.

Comment: have you added more other jQuery in this page..? if yes then just make comment that files for a while and check your task for what you are asking is working or not..?

Comment: Yeah. The main page have a jQuery call. And the iFrame have other jQuery call. The same.

Comment: yes, then this could be create prob with your task..just remove/comment jquery other then use in iFrame. and then check.

Comment: both means ? in what other then iFrame.?

Comment: Here is the flow: First the user enter to a page. In a column, the user can upload an image by clicking on a button. When you click at the button, the .show() method shows the iFrame below. Inside the iFrame, we have the code above (it calls to jQuery on [{scripts}])

Comment: ok..fine. you can refer this link also for what you are doing..[Click here](http://www.akchauhan.com/upload-image-using-hidden-iframe/)